# How can I disable xtrace and preserve my exit code

Tags: shell, debugging, exit-status

I'm trying to figure out a good way to disable xtrace before leaving a script. These are all being executed by Wercker, a continuous integration and deployment SaaS.

A previous script of mine has run enabling xtrace

```
+ echo 7ad27e6b-75d9-4e72-a9a7-8b0d6796bd75 0
source "/pipeline/maven-9ea06b71-4392-4fec-ab5a-db7389b49cf2/run.sh" < /dev/null
+ source /pipeline/maven-9ea06b71-4392-4fec-ab5a-db7389b49cf2/run.sh
++ set +o xtrace ## disabling here to keep other area's quiet
...
++ '[' -e settings.xml ']'
++ SETTINGS=--settings=settings.xml
++ mvn --update-snapshots --batch-mode -Dmaven.repo.local=/pipeline/cache --settings=settings.xml deploy
...
+ echo f5b142ac-a369-4166-967e-688d46c642c8 0
```

here's [my actual code](https://bitbucket.org/xenoterracide/wercker-step-maven/src/8d138b84dd9676d8c677d439c9ea9e1c1a1efad1/run.sh?at=master)

```
if [ -n "$WERCKER_MAVEN_DEBUG" ]; then
    set -o xtrace
    case "$WERCKER_MAVEN_DEBUG" in
        [1-2]) env;;
        [1-3]) DEBUG="--debug";;
    esac
fi

if [ -e "$WERCKER_MAVEN_SETTINGS" ]; then
   SETTINGS="--settings=${WERCKER_MAVEN_SETTINGS}"
fi

mvn --update-snapshots \
    --batch-mode \
    -Dmaven.repo.local=${WERCKER_CACHE_DIR} \
    ${SETTINGS} ${DEBUG} \
    ${WERCKER_MAVEN_GOALS}
```

when I try to disable xtrace with `set +o xtrace` at the bottom of the file that changed the return to always be 0, and so even if maven was failing ci wasn't. I then tried to capture mavens return and call `exit  ${STATUS}` but this caused it to fail even when maven was succeeding with status 0. I think that had something to do with calling exit, not with how I was capturing the code.

How can I disable `xtrace` after `mvn` has been executed while preserving mavens return status for the caller script?

Answer (score 3):

I refactored the code into functions, the function that matters for this case is `disable_xtrace_and_return_status` and how it returns the status captured from running maven. Though I've deceived myself into thinking this was working before...

```
function disable_xtrace_and_return_status() {
    set +o xtrace
    return $1
}

function run() {
    if [ -n "$WERCKER_MAVEN_DEBUG" ]; then
        if [ "$WERCKER_MAVEN_DEBUG" -ge "1" ]; then
            set -o xtrace

            if [ "$WERCKER_MAVEN_DEBUG" -ge "2" ]; then
                env

                if [ "$WERCKER_MAVEN_DEBUG" -ge "3" ]; then
                    local debug="--debug"
                fi
            fi
        fi
    fi

    if [ -e "$WERCKER_MAVEN_SETTINGS" ]; then
       local settings="--settings=${WERCKER_MAVEN_SETTINGS}"
    fi

    mvn --update-snapshots \
        --batch-mode \
        -Dmaven.repo.local=${WERCKER_CACHE_DIR} \
        ${settings} ${debug} \
        ${WERCKER_MAVEN_GOALS}

   disable_xtrace_and_return_status $?
}

run;
```

Comment: Why did you use `sh` syntax in original script but using `bash` syntax here?

Comment: oh is something about this bash specific? I didn't check, and I don't really have control over the shell they get run in. :/. Though I did test them locally on zsh without issue... (asside from missing log functions)

Comment: `function name()` is ksh syntax, copied by `bash` and `zsh`. It's not in POSIX sh.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your function in a subshell, made the `set -o xtrace` only affected in subshell environment:

```
run() (
  if [ -n "$WERCKER_MAVEN_DEBUG" ]; then
      set -o xtrace
      case "$WERCKER_MAVEN_DEBUG" in
          [1-2]) env;;
          [1-3]) DEBUG="--debug";;
      esac
  fi

  if [ -e "$WERCKER_MAVEN_SETTINGS" ]; then
      SETTINGS="--settings=${WERCKER_MAVEN_SETTINGS}"
  fi

  mvn --update-snapshots \
      --batch-mode \
      -Dmaven.repo.local=${WERCKER_CACHE_DIR} \
      ${SETTINGS} ${DEBUG} \
      ${WERCKER_MAVEN_GOALS}
)

run
printf '%s\n' "$?"
```

Simple test:

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/sh

run() (
  set -o xtrace
  return 1
)

run
printf '%s\n' "$?"
```

Run it:

```
$ ./test.sh
+ return 1
1
```

Comment: I now ask myself why they aren't subshelling these things to begin with...